# ng build --prod does not build the code

Tags: angular

i executed the command:-

ng bild --prod

**here i am using**

node version:- v6.11.0

@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2

typescript : Version 2.4.2

**throws errors listed below:-**

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\Shashikant D Drive\Ishir Projects\EZForms\
    ezforms-server\public\src'
     @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
     @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir async
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Shashikant D Drive\Ishir Projects\EZForms\ezforms-server\public\src\$$_gendir\app+c
    ompleted\completed.module.ngfactory.ts' in 'D:\Shashikant D Drive\Ishir Projects\EZForms\ezforms-server\public\src\$$_gendir'
     @ ./src/$$_gendir async
     @ ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
     @ ./src/main.ts
     @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir async
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Shashikant D Drive\Ishir Projects\EZForms\ezforms-server\public\src\$$_gendir\app+d
    ashboard\dashboard.module.ngfactory.ts' in 'D:\Shashikant D Drive\Ishir Projects\EZForms\ezforms-server\public\src\$$_gendir'
     @ ./src/$$_gendir async
     @ ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
     @ ./src/main.ts
     @ multi ./src/main.ts

Here is the attached image which contains application files structure.

[image]

Comment: `ng build --env = prod`

Comment: It throws, Environment "=" does not exist.
Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related with a bug in angular-cli version.

Try installing `npm install enhanced-resolve@3.3.0`

or upgrade your angular-cli and Angular to the latest version (1.0.0-rc.2 is really old, latest is 1.2.6).

I suggest the latter; you can follow the documentation to upgrade your cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

Source to the issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4551#issuecomment-317459157

Comment: Thanks echonax, I am just going to upgrade it and let you know.

Comment: That worked echonax.
once i ran the command ng build --prod
i was show some variables not defined or kind of private variable not accessible. then i created those all variables. now it worked. 
thanks (y)
you rock!.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the errors in your project with `ng build --prod --verbose`